# How to assign values based on another data frame with different number of elements?

Tags: r

Here is a reproducible example:

```
data <- data.frame(A1=c("ao","ao","zo","ao","zo","ao","jo","jo","ko"),B1=c("y1","y1","y2","y2","y1","y1","y2","y2","y1"))

> data
  A1 B1
1 ao y1
2 ao y1
3 zo y2
4 ao y2
5 zo y1
6 ao y1
7 jo y2
8 jo y2
9 ko y1

sor <- data.frame(A1=c("ao","ko","jo","zo","po"),y1=c(10,20,30,0,50),y2=c(22,33,44,55,66))

> sor
  A1 y1 y2
1 ao 10 22
2 ko 20 33
3 jo 30 44
4 zo  0 55
5 po 50 66
```

Here, `data` is the main data frame and `sor` is the standard data frame. I want to create a new column `VAL` in `data` and assign values based on the data frame `sor` (check has to be made in rows and columns) and an NA is it is not present in `sor`.

This is the required Output.

```
> data
  A1 B1 VAL
1 ao y1  10
2 ao y1  10
3 zo y2  55
4 ao y2  22
5 zo y1   0
6 ao y1  10
7 jo y2  44
8 jo y2  44
9 ko y1  20
```

This is possible using for-loops and I have tired and got the result using for-loops. But I have a large number of rows in my data frame and using for loops will not be efficient.

Is there an efficient way to do this other than using for-loops in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, we can create a matrix of row-column index with `match` and use it to subset values from `sor` and create a new column.

```
data$VAL <- as.numeric(sor[cbind(match(data$A1,sor$A1),match(data$B1, names(sor)))])
data

#  A1 B1 VAL
#1 ao y1  10
#2 ao y1  10
#3 zo y2  55
#4 ao y2  22
#5 zo y1   0
#6 ao y1  10
#7 jo y2  44
#8 jo y2  44
#9 ko y1  20
```

---

Or we can get `sor` in long format and then join.

```
library(dplyr)
sor %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -A1, names_to = 'B1') %>%
  right_join(data, by = c('A1', 'B1'))
```

Comment: in base R you can simply do `cbind(data,val = \`rownames<-\`(sor,sor$A1)[as.matrix(data)])`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[sor, VAL := i.y1, on = "A1"]

#    A1 B1 VAL
# 1: ao y1  10
# 2: ao y1  10
# 3: zo y2   0
# 4: ao y2  10
# 5: zo y1   0
# 6: ao y1  10
# 7: jo y2  30
# 8: jo y2  30
# 9: ko y1  20
```